# Merge several objects into one object and combine properties JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have multiple objects inside an array, I want to merge all the objects that has the same id, but I want to combine all the values from one property as well (In this case, channels)

This is the code:

```
defaultArray = [
  {
    id: "FirstId",
    name: "Some random name"
    channels: [{
      id: "Channel-ASD",
      name: "Channel ASD"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: "FirstId",
    name: "Some random name"
    channels: [{
      id: "Channel-QWE",
      name: "Channel QWE"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: "SecondId",
    name: "Some random name"
    channels: [{
      id: "Channel-QAZ",
      name: "Channel QAZ"
    }]
  }
];
```

Expected output:

```
newArray = [
  {
    id: "FirstId",
    name: "Some random name"
    channels: [
      {
        id: "Channel-ASD",
        name: "Channel ASD"
      },
      {
        id: "Channel-QWE",
        name: "Channel QWE"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "SecondId",
    name: "Some random name"
    channels: [{
      id: "Channel-QAZ",
      name: "Channel QAZ"
    }]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to study about `filter`, `map`, `reduce`, `some`, ...

```js
let defaultArray = [
  {
    id: "FirstId",
    name: "Some random name",
    channels: [{
      id: "Channel-ASD",
      name: "Channel ASD"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: "FirstId",
    name: "Some random name",
    channels: [{
      id: "Channel-QWE",
      name: "Channel QWE"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: "SecondId",
    name: "Some random name",
    channels: [{
      id: "Channel-QAZ",
      name: "Channel QAZ"
    }]
  }
];

let transformed= defaultArray.reduce((result, item, index, original)=>{
  if (result.some(i=>i.id===item.id)) return result;
  let channels = original.reduce((r,i)=>{
    i.id===item.id && (r=[...r, ...i.channels]);
    return r;
  },[]);

  result.push({
    ...item,
    channels
  });
  return result;
},[]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(transformed,null,2));
```